# Set Android Tabs with different width

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

I have 4 tabs currently and they are all the same width. I would like the last tab to be less wide than the others. I tried using LayoutParams to specify the width but this didn't seem to work.

```
TextView view = new TextView(this);
view.setText("Hello");
LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10,10);
view.setLayoutParams(lp);
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(view).setTabListener(this));
```

This is what it currently looks like
[image: Tab bar with 4 tabs]

I want the fourth tab to be an overflow button. Something like the image is what I'm going for. If there was a way to have only 3 tabs and then an overflow button at the edge that would be perfect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It will be possible using fragments.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: Just take horizontal linearlayout with 2 fragments, 1st fragment contains tablayout, and second fragment contains buttons.